# Delphi invalid pointer operation using ADO

Tags: delphi, ado

When calling this code more than once (It's called on the change of a combobox), I'm getting the error "Operation not allowed when the object is open" on the second change and on the third onwards i'm getting "invalid pointer operation".

```
if loadfile.Database <> nil then  
    loadfile.Database.destroy;  
Loadfile.Database := Tdatabase.create(CardSets.Text, false);  
LoadFile.Database.create(CardSets.Text, false);         
refreshlist;
```

The create code is just

```
DataSource :=   
    'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' +   
    ';Data Source=' + Path +  
    ';Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5';   
with MainWindow do  
begin   
    ADOConnection.ConnectionString := Datasource;   
    ADOConnection.LoginPrompt := False;   
end;
```

And refreshlist just updates a visual list of the data in the database.

I've looked at some similar stackoverflow questions but i am unable to see how the answers could help my problem.

Side question, When to use .Destroy or .Free? .Free in this case just gives a different error.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling `create` twice?

Comment: Anyway, use `FreeAndNil` - neither `destroy` nor `free` set the value to nil.

Comment: Is that not how you create an object? NVM: I'm an idiot , thanks!

Comment: Any time you see two dots in the same expression, that suggests your design is weak. You should not be assigning to LoadFile.Database. A method in the class of LoadFile should be assigning to Database. It would seem that Database is read/write. Step 1 is to make it read only, or even private. More broadly it looks like your model is mixed in with your GUI. That's a mess.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're calling `Create` twice; the second is unnecessary:

```
if loadfile.Database <> nil then  
    loadfile.Database.destroy;  
Loadfile.Database := Tdatabase.create(CardSets.Text, false);  // First call
LoadFile.Database.create(CardSets.Text, false);               // Second call
```

Change your code to simply:

```
LoadFile.Database.Free;
LoadFile.Database := TDatabase.Create(CardSets.Text, False);
```

Second, never directly call `Destroy`. Use `Free` instead, as it checks first for an unassigned pointer and then calls `Destroy` if it's safe to do so. `TObject.Free` is basically this code:

```
procedure TObject.Free;
begin
  if Self <> nil then
    Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: If i call  `Loadfile.Database.Free` when the object hasn't been created will i get an error? So is the If business useless?

Comment: You've not provided enough context. The constructor of LoadFile (whatever that is) should be creating the initial database instance; I'm not sure how it would get accessed before it is created. I'm not even clear why you'd want to free the database and recreate it, frankly. You can simply disconnect, change the connection string, and then reconnect, without the overhead of calling the constructor at all.

Comment: To directly answer your comment's question, however: `TObject.Free` checks first to ensure `Self <> nil` before calling the destructor (you can see that yourself in `System.pas`). The code there is `if Self <> nil then Destroy;`. (See my edited answer.)

Comment: Loadfile is a form, and (currently) the TDatabase object is pretty much just a holder for a bunch of database altering functions and the holder of an ADOX_TLB catalog type. Yes i see what you're saying, my way is a bit convoluted. Thanks